# Put the Meta back in Meta Arqade

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

I noticed that the Arqade Meta doesn't have "Meta" in its logo. Was this purposeful or accidental?

Not a top priority, but I suggest that Arqade Meta has the Meta text in its logo.

Comment: There is a usability issue here: to someone *completely* colour-blind (Wikipedia says [1/30,000 people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochromacy)) main and meta are indistinguishable.

Comment: @fredley Colour-blind users can still read URLs

Comment: Looks like this was changed using the accepted answer's design, so I'm tagging as status-completed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took the liberty of creating a new vector graphic with the 'meta' included.
I'm not a vector graphics pro, but using Inkscape and copying and manipulating the existing objects I was able to create something reasonable:

[image: New Meta graphic at 200%]

And a screenshot of how that will look (the vague horizontal line in the 't' has been fixed):

[image]

The SVG can be found [here](https://joachimbeens.com/files/arqade_meta_new.svg).

Alternatively (in response to JMac's comment):

[image]

The corresponding SVG can be found [here](https://joachimbeens.com/files/arqade_meta_new_alt_alpha.svg).

Comment: The only thing I would suggest different would be having the word meta be smaller than Arqade.  I find it makes it look closer to the main site, while still making the differences obvious.  This also seems to be how most sites with designs handle it.

Comment: @JMac like this ↑ ?

Comment: Nice.  I was just thinking making the word smaller, but that red box looks like a good touch to me.

Comment: @JMac Yeah, I think I know what you were referring to, but looking for an svg file, I found this on StackOverflow Meta, and thought it would add a nice accent.

Comment: I like the image with the red box as well.

Comment: Amazing work! I'm gonna add an answer to our CM review post to hopefully get this one addressed

Comment: Woohoo! This is done :D

Comment: @Robotnik Yeah, awesome! :D